# DELETE in angularjs - 405 Method not allowed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The error I get, which means that it wont execute my delete method from angular:

```
DELETE http://localhost:49717/api/Item?iid=D1 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

My app.js

```
'use strict';

var SalesApp = angular.module('SalesApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']).
     config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', { controller: ItemCtrl, templateUrl: 'item.html' }).
            when('/new', { controller: CreateCtrl, templateUrl: 'details.html' }).
            when('/edit/:editId', { controller: EditCtrl, templateUrl: 'details.html' }).
            otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
     }]);

SalesApp.factory('Item', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/Item/:id', { id: '@id' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' } });
});




var ItemCtrl = function ($scope, $location, Item) {    

    $scope.delete = function () {
        var id = this.item.iid;
        Item.delete({ iid: id }), function () {
            $('#item_' + id).fadeOut();
        };
    };
};
```

The appropiate part of the html of the index.html

```
<tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items" id="item_{{item.iid}}">
            <td>{{item.iid}}</td>
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.price}}</td>
            <td><a ng-click="delete()">X</a></td>
            <td><a href="#/edit/{{item.iid}}"><div class="edit">Edit</div></a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

And my script imports:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
```

It may be some silly misstake of me, I'm not quite sure, the add and update works? My first thought was that it could be some foreign key spooking, but I tried deleting an item using sql server and it worked just fine.

Added back-end:

```
// DELETE api/Item/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(Item))]
        public IHttpActionResult DeleteItem(string id)
        {
            Item item = db.Item.Find(id);
            if (item == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            db.Item.Remove(item);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return Ok(item);
        }
```

Comment: It means that your webserver is not able to support this DELETE request method. You either configure it or use POST.

Comment: Create and send request (delete on specified url) using fiddler and you will see there this error. I mean something is wrong at back end system. Please provide some details from the backend code.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put the following code before your `$http({url:"your-url-here",method:"DELETE",params:{your-parameters}})`
 line to ensure that DELETE works.

`$http.defaults.headers["delete"] = {
     'Content-Type':'application/json,charset=utf-8'
};`